# Translation Not Working from Magento Admin

Tags: magento, templates, admin, community-translations

I have a situation where in the actions I trigger from Admin website do not translate my content. I have custom modules in magento and one of them is responsible for sending out emails. The email contents are to be translate according to the locale of the store. While everything works fine when done automatically. But when I trigger this sending of emails from the admin panel the translations aren't working.

For example, my code uses the magento magic method,

> __("Text to be translated")

and when the corresponding text is translated in my website. But when I trigger an action from the admin, the same content is not translated.

My translate.csv is currently located in,

```
app      
 design
    frontend
       MyModule
         default
           locale
             country  
              translate.csv
```

Any help will be appreciated.